# How to Add 1 to a number represented as linked list using Python In the below code format?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I have a linked list with 1999 which I reversed to get 9991. However I am getting None as an output when calling add_one function for the below singly linked list coding exercise. I supposed to be getting 0002 after applying add_one function to 9991. And once I will apply reverse function it will be 2000. Kindly help me with the below code as to where it is going wrong?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value= value
        self.next = None
        
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self,value):
        new_node=Node(value)
        self.head=new_node
        self.tail=new_node
        self.length=1
        
    def print_list(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp is not None:
            print(temp.value)
            temp = temp.next   
        
        
    def append(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        self.length += 1
        return True        
    
    def reverse_list(self):
        temp=self.head
        self.head=self.tail
        self.tail=temp
        after = temp.next
        before=None
        for _ in range(self.length):
            after=temp.next
            temp.next=before
            before=temp
            temp=after
            
    def add_one(self):
        carry=0
        prev=None
        self.head.value+=1
        while (self.head!=None) and (self.head.value>9 or carry>0):
            prev=self.head
            self.head.value+=carry
            carry=self.head.value//10
            self.head.value=self.head.value%10
            self.head=self.head.next


        if carry>0:
            prev.next=Node(carry)
        return prev.next
            
        
my_linked_list = LinkedList(1)
my_linked_list.append(9)
my_linked_list.append(9)
my_linked_list.append(9)
my_linked_list.print_list()
my_linked_list.reverse_list()
my_linked_list.print_list()
my_linked_list.add_one()
my_linked_list.print_list()
```

Comment: Why would you want to change `self.head`? That should constantly be pointing to the head of the list. After the `add_one` function is done, `self.head` will point to `None` as per the while loop requirement.

Comment: Use a local variable to walk down the list, not `self.head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your `add_one` function to the following:

```py
def add_one(self):
    carry = 1  # Start with a carry of 1
    prev = None  # Keep track of the previous node
    current = self.head  # Start from the head of the linked list

    while current is not None:
        prev = current  # Update the previous node
        new_value = current.value + carry  # Add the value of the current node with the carry
        carry = new_value // 10  # Calculate the new carry
        current.value = new_value % 10  # Update the value of the current node with the remainder
        current = current.next  # Move on to the next node

    if carry > 0:
        # If there's still a carry left, create a new node for it
        new_node = Node(carry)
        prev.next = new_node  # Link the new node with the previous node
        self.length += 1  # Increase the length of the linked list

    return prev  # Return the previous node
```

This will ensure it adds one to the linked list when it is reversed.

Answer (score 1):

In your iteration you are using `self.head` to store which element you are processing:

```
    def add_one(self):
        carry=0
        prev=None
        self.head.value+=1
        while (self.head!=None) and (self.head.value>9 or carry>0):
            prev=self.head
            self.head.value+=carry
            carry=self.head.value//10
            self.head.value=self.head.value%10
            self.head=self.head.next  #<----------- HERE!
```

At the end of that loop, `self.head` will be at the end of your list, i.e. after the last element. What you want is to use a temporary variable instead:

```
    def add_one(self):
        if self.head is not None:

            # Apply addition to the head and calculate carry
            self.head.value += 1
            carry = self.head.value // 10
            self.head.value = self.head.value % 10

            # set up pointers
            current=self.head.next
            prev = self.head
            while (current is not None) and (current.value > 9 or carry > 0):
                # In your loop, we only act on current
                current.value += carry
                carry = current.value // 10
                current.value = current.value % 10
                # move forward, but only using the tmp varaibles, leaving self.head intact
                prev=current
                current = current.next

            if carry > 0:
                prev.next = Node(carry)
            return prev.next
```

With this modification, your above code would correctly produce

```
1
9
9
9
9
9
9
1
0
0
0
2
```